# Display data on jsp based on selected date from Liferay datepicker

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I have a datepicker. What I want to achieve is: based on the date selected by user, the data for that day should be displayed on the jsp.
I have used a serveResource function for displaying some data in some other form.
Should I create another such function such that based on selected date, data is displayed for that particular data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `serveResource` so you want to fetch data using ajax.

Unfortunately you can't have `resourceURL` behave the same as `actionURL` in otherwords you can't have multiple methods for serving `resourceRequest` like you have to serve `actionRequest`.

1. So either you can use `actionURL` to call different methods but would refresh the page which you don't want as I see
2. OR, else you can set a parameter in the `resourceURL` to let the `serveResource` method know what you want to return and then in the `serveResource` method of the portlet have `switch-case` or `if-else` to determine from where has this request come.

Going with the second approach:

You jsp would look something like this (might not work as it is):

```html
<aui:button value="Click to get today's data" onClick="fetchCurrentDateData()" />

<portlet:resourceURL var="currentDateDataResourceURL" >
    <portlet:param name="whicData" value="currentDateData" />
</portlet:resourceURL>

<aui:script>
    function fetchCurrentDateData() {
        A.io.request(
                    currentDateDataResourceURL, {
                        dataType: 'text', // since you might want to execute a JSP and return HTML code
                        on: {
                                success: function(event, id, xhr) {
                                    A.one("#theDivWhereNeedsToBeDisplayed").html(this.get('responseData'));
                                },
                                failure: function(event, id, xhr){

                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
</aui:script>
```

Your `serveResource` method would be something like this (I am assuming your portlet extends `MVCPortlet` class of liferay):

```java
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) {
    String strWhichData = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "whicData");

    if (strWhichData.equals("currentDateData")){

        // call service layer to fetch all the current date data

        // this is a method in MVCPortlet if you are extending liferay's MVCPortlet
        include("/html/myportlet/viewCurrentData.jsp", resourceRequest, resourceResponse);

    } else if (strWhichData.equals("otherAjaxStuff")) {

        // do you other stuff and return JSON or HTML as you see fit

    } else {

        // do your normal stuff
        // can return JSON or HTML as you see fit
    }
}
```

**Note:**
As a side-note you can try [Spring MVC portlet](http://www.liferaysolution.com/2013/05/ajax-call-using-resource-url-spring-mvc.html#.Uab1oZyKnQg) which gives you the ability to have different methods for serving `resourceRequest`.

Comment: Prakash I used your approach. I retrieved the date in serveResource. Is there a way I can store the json object in a variable and display it using liferay search container?

Comment: @SeeyaK In the first `if` condition you don't need JSON you can just pass a `List` of data and in the include-JSP you can use liferay-search-container, I don't think that should be a problem. But then using the pagination of Liferay search container might pose a problem. Anyways you can always ask another question and get answers for that if you are stuck. Thanks

Comment: Yes I have had pagination problem before. I will ask about it in another forum. I have code in if and I am doing other stuff in else part of the serve resource. works well. U said to include-jsp in the first if and use the data in search container. How do I call this data in jsp after I include the jsp page name in the serveresource method?

Comment: ___How do I call this data in jsp___, as you normally do i.e. set it as an attribute in request or try calling the service related code in the JSP itself using scriptlets (scoffed at by JSP community but Liferay does this often) :-)

Comment: What I mean is right now I am passing it as json array. How do I capture it in search container? Normally I make a function call to fetch data and retrieve it in search container.. How do I call it from serveresource method. I have many "if else"? I included the "include" statement in serveresource.. How do I call it in my jsp? I wanted an example how to do that..

Comment: Since the JSP you pass in `include()` would be executed as normal JSPs do, you can make a method call from the JSP itself like you normally do, say, `MyUtil.getTotalResults()`. There is no difference in the way you do things in JSPs.

Comment: I dont think Iunderstood it. Or may be I am asking a dumb ques ;)
So what you mean is call the serveresource method in jsp? Becasue I am fetching the results in the serveresource method and at present I am passing jsonarray to the jsp..
And this operations are in the first if of the serveresource

Comment: Ok I understand. We are talking about 2 JSPs here, (1) first, through which the ajax function calls the `serveResource` method (2) second, the JSP which will be included by the `include` method in `serveResource` method. I was talking referring the second and it seems you were talking about the first :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter under resourceURL and check that parameter under serveResorce method. Based on that parameter call your function or code

i.e

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="userdetail" >
<portlet:param name="userinfo" value="true"></portlet:param>
</portlet:resourceURL>
```